# Add +2 years based on created date in SharePoint using powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-server

I want to add a date based on item created date +2 years for all existing items in the New Column `Date` , can any one help on this using PowerShell?

Example:

```
Created date: 7/9/2015
Date:         7/9/2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://<sitecollection>/<subsite>
$lList=$spWeb.Lists["<ListName>"]  
$spItems = $lList.GetItems()
foreach($spItem in $spItems)
{
    $spItem["Date"] = $spItem["Created"].AddYears(2)
    $spItem.Update()
}
```